# How to enforce compiler generic code using e.g. clang warnings??

Tags: c++, clang++

I've been developing a support library for various c++17 projects for a few years.

In order to minimize problems and maximize portability I have been using strict standards compliant c++17 and no extensions as well as compiling with both default GCC and clang on Ubuntu 20.04 along with wall wextra etc fixing all.

Recently I tried to compile to code using msvs19 but the sheer number of outright compilation errors stunned me.

Is there any way to configure clang to warn on features that won't compile in msvs or aren't supported by msvs?

Like a way to explicitly warn on all not yet implemented standard features or inconsistently implemented standard festures. The lib provides alot of metatemplate stuff, like for(auto& [a,b,c,...]:zip(as,bs,..) which hits inconsistencies or outright compiler crashes when implemented straightforwardly, or differ between compilers. Making maintainable a pain as I lack dedicated build VM servers.

Also what is the best way to get float128 i.e. standards compliant long double in msvs? Does not have to be that long double is float128, just that it exists?

Comment: Unsure whether this is really *on topic* here, hence only posting a comment. A common answer to portability is to use a Continuous Integration service like Travis CI or AppVeyor or ... (put here your prefered system including a locally hosted one using Jenkins). Most of them give access to different OS versions and some have a number of build systems. If you managed to setup automated tests you can control the portability of the code all along the development process.

Comment: @SergeBallesta You have my vote for "on topic". It definitly seems an insightful contribution to this. I.e. I consider it at least an appreciated "partial answer".

Comment: Could you include a few (1 or 2)  concrete examples please ([mcve]), perhaps with a godbolt link?  Also I can't find a Standard reference to `float128`.

Comment: @RichardCritten: For example gcc and Clang both accept VLA in C++ while MSVC does not (not even in C anyway)...

Comment: But all of clang, GCC and MSVC reject - VLAs live - https://godbolt.org/z/1MxPnE8Er  First stage in cross tool-chain coding is to strictly enforce Standards compliance so as to avoid potential problems.

Comment: Serges answer would be the standard approach, and I would do it if I had the resources for that, but last time I tried a local host it was too slow to simultaneously develop on, and I also struggled to get the windows system working. Its been a few years though, might be worth a look. 

hmm I think I read somewhere that long double should be 128, but perhaps its just that both gcc and clang do so and its not actually standard.

Comment: I do have every kind of not a strict c++ warning on so strict standards compliance should be the case. Well that or the flag disabling extensions and the warning on non standards has false negatives. 

Runtime variable sized stack arrays isnt a problem, I learned what stack overflow is a long time ago and disabled it then. Havent ever really needed it either. 

I have already fixed all the compiler errors I got. 
The problem is now I'm going to dump windows again, and in six months it wont work again.